# Error when installing memcache gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am running gem install memcache -v '1.2.13', and I am getting this error on ruby 1.9.3 on OSX 10.8

```
ld: library not found for -lruby.1.9.1
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [native_server.bundle] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/memcache-1.2.13 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/memcache-1.2.13/ext/gem_make.out
```

I have no idea what to do at this point.

Comment: Do you have `memcached` installed?

Answer (score 0):

Ok maybe it's a bit late, but for everybody with the same problem, you can look at my post which is about the same topic. I found a solution for this problem.

--> [Error while installing memcache (1.2.13)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19910329/error-while-installing-memcache-1-2-13?lq=1)

Hope that helps you too! ;-)